# Identification of a purple flower

Tags: botany, species-identification, flowers

[image]

What is this purple flower? Picture taken from a garden in India.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It closely looks like [***Tibouchina urvilleana***](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tibouchina_urvilleana_flower_leaves_ja.jpg)<sup>*</sup> or any other *Tibouchina* species. You can have a look [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibouchina).

[image]

<sup>[[Source:Wikimedia common](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tibouchina_urvilleana_flower_leaves_ja.jpg)]</sup>

> *Tibouchina urvilleana* is a species of flowering plant in the family Melastomataceae, native to Brazil. Growing to 3–6 m (10–20 ft) tall by 2–3 m (7–10 ft) wide, it is a sprawling evergreen shrub with longitudinally veined, dark green hairy leaves. Clusters of brilliant purple flowers up to 10 cm (4 in) in diameter, with black stamens, are borne throughout summer and autumn.[[Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibouchina_urvilleana)]

<sup>*</sup><sub>Credits to @RHA for suggesting the right species.</sub>

Comment: Thnx. It looks like that